# Pandas - Filter based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a problem when I need to exclude some rows from by dataframe.

here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dff = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Default': [1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
    'Default_Amount': [1200,2000,0,350,0,760,0],
    'Tot_Amount': [1200,2000,3400,350,10000,760,7500],
    'Time' : ['October','March','November','November','January','December','January'],
    'Class': ['A','B','A','A','B','B','A']
}
dff = pd.DataFrame(dff)
display(dff)

dff[(dff.Time != 'November') & (dff.Default == 1) ]
```

What I am trying to do, is to exclude the row in dataframe that has the following two conditions: time = November with default = 1 (that is the ID 4 in the dataframe).

But if I execute this code "`dff[(dff.Time != 'November') & (dff.Default == 1) ]`", it excludes also  the other time = "November" and default = 0.

How can I avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need match not equal `dff.Default != 1` with bitwise `OR` by `|`:

```
df = dff[(dff.Time != 'November') | (dff.Default != 1) ]
```

Or invert mask, but change `|` to `&` for bitwise `AND` and change `!=` to `==`:

```
df = dff[~((dff.Time == 'November') & (dff.Default == 1)) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple boolean algebra

Either follow [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and invert both conditions while getting an OR (`|`):

```
dff[(dff.Time != 'November') | (dff.Default != 1) ]
```

or add (`&`) your two conditions, and negate (`~`):

```
dff[~((dff.Time == 'November') & (dff.Default == 1)) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use

```
dff[dff.ID != 4]
```

or otherwise you can use

```
dff[~((dff.Time == 'November') & (dff.Default == 1))]
```

The problem with you code is that
`(dff.Time != 'November')` first selects all non-November rows and then `(dff.Default == 1)` selects all row with Default '1' only.